# VMWare Fusion 4.0 + Postgres

Tags: windows-7, postgresql, vmware-fusion

The setup:

- Mac OS X Lion, PostgreSQL 9.0.4 Host
- Windows 7 VM

I used to be able to connect from the VM to Postgres via pgAdmin and / or the software I'm developing on Windows just fine.  That was with VMF 3.x.  Since I've upgraded to VMF 4.0 I can no longer.  I've checked Mac firewall settings (it's not running), whether new IP addresses for the DHCP server or the VM had been assigned (no), and rechecked pg_hba.conf (still looks fine).

I'm getting the dreaded:

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is
>   the server running on host "192.168.244.2" and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there were two different "vmnet" interfaces on the Host.  The network that serves DHCP leases is not the same as the network where Postgres resides.  Using the latter's IP address fixed it.